# Shehechiyanu on Mishloach Manos and Matonos L'Evyonim

Tags: halacha, purim, shehecheyanu

When we say Shehechiyanu in the morning by Kriyas HaMegila they announce in my Shul to have in mind the Mitzvos HaYom of Mishloach Manos, Matonos L'Evyonim, and Seudas Purim. Can you give Mishloach Manos or Matanos L'Evyonim prior to hearing the Megila in the morning with the Shehechiyanu?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80867

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Magen Avraham* says that if one did not have a *m'gila* one would not say *birkas "shehechiyanu"*. This leads me to believe that if one had not read yet the *halacha* would be the same.

Rav Ya'akov Emden (in *Mor Uk'tzi'a*) challenges the premise, pointing out that we say the *b'racha* on *Yom Kipur* without an action necessarily associated with its recital, and the same should be possible on *Purim*. His logic is presumably based on the *g'mara* in *Eruvin*, even though he does not cite the reference for being able to say the *b'racha* in the *shuk*.

Comment: R' Yaakov Emden actually does quote the statement in Eruvin, זמן אומרו אפי' בשוק - he just doesn't give the source reference. But anyway, he goes on to say that in that case *shehecheyanu* should be said over a cup of wine during the Purim seudah - i.e., evidently he agrees with Magen Avraham that it should not be recited over mishloach manos or matanos la'evyonim.