# Other mitzvos hayom before megilla

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, tzedakah-charity, gifts, shehecheyanu

When making the blessing *shehecheyanu* before the *megilla*, one should have in mind that the blessing should cover the other *mitzvos* of *Purim*. But what if the *megilla* reading will be later, and one wants to give *mishloach manos* or *matanos l'evyonim* before hearing *megilla*? Should one then say *shehecheyanu* right away?

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6327

Comment: *(Up for grabs! The answer (and the comment on it) over there answer this question also.)*

Comment: Tangential reading (related to whether the shechyanu is on those mitzvos at all http://dafyomi.co.il/megilah/discuss/mg-qa-007.2.htm

Comment: Source for first sentence?

Comment: @mevaqesh Says in all the siddurim, megillos, and chumashim that I've looked in